# How to use facebook and dropbox sdk in one iOS app

Tags: ios, sdk

I am using facebook sdk for login and dropbox sdk in single app, but when I launch the app on the simulator, it is giving me the following error

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation).

I have initiated both sdks in same method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough information, Xcode will usually give you more "telling" errors elsewhere.

Those other error messages probably hint at the cause of your linker error.

e.g.: 
a) you included a module twice, "duplicate symbol".

b) you failed to declare or include a framework inside a source file.

c) you are using an old version of the framework, which won't "bit-compile" with newer versions of Xcode (Xcode version >= 7.0)

d) you have a syntax error somewhere else, causing that module to fail linking as well.

e) one or more of the framework you added does not include all the architectures required by your project

g) the project comes from another user, and some hard path, referencing a directory which exists only on that user machine is contained in the project.

These are the first few things which come to my mind.

I strongly suggest you clarify your question.